# Organization Chart for JavaScript

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript, software-development

I am trying to see if there is any kind of responsive template, library or whatever it helps me to create an Organization Chart, it should be based on JavaScript.

I need something like [this](http://jointjs.com/demos/org).

That is just a plugin, I need something more complex. Could be a plugin with template included or something related.

Comment: What is your budget? Or should it be gratis, or even open source?

Comment: "I need something like this" is not a great description because everyone will focus on a different feature there. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and edit your question, it has potential to become a great question :-)

Comment: "Responsive" means that elements will reorganize themselves automatically when viewed on a small screen. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Do you want the chart to be editable from the web interface? Or do you want to define it in JavaScript and then just view it from the web interface? Please edit your question to make these things clear, then ask us to reopen. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including org charts.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

With [GoJS](http://gojs.net), you can create arbitrarily complex node templates, and layout nodes automatically.

[Small, editable org chart with interactive features](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html)

[image: GoJS org chart]

[Larger org chart with overview](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartStatic.html)

[image: GoJS org chart]